# Javascript Auto Suggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

Is there a library available for Auto Suggest/Complete for cases like the following

Searching for "Vir" returns both "West Virginia" and "Virginia"

Thanks

**EDIT**

Sorry for not explaining it more. In the problem above, I do not want a "contains" search, but a prefix search on word boundaries. So "est" should not return "West Virginia", but "wes" or "vir" should.

The list is around 500 items large.

**Proposed Solution**

I modified the trie implementation by Mike de Boer https://github.com/mikedeboer/trie to solve this. I split an item on word boundaries and stored each word in the trie. For the last letter of each word I stored the index of the item that the word came from in the trie node. When user searches, I return a list of indices and then get the corresponding items from the main list.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Are you using only Javascript, like you have a js object file and want to filter the objects that match, or you have a backend application (PHP, Python, ...) that will retrieve a JSON for you already filtered?

Comment: Javascript based. No interaction with any backend application. I have a list of about 500 items.

Comment: Sugest you to create your object filter using some library like underscore.js http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter as you like, then you can persist it on some plugin or program your own Auto Suggest component :)

Comment: @GabrielGartz I have updated the question with a proposed solution. Tell me what you think. I am not going with an iterative solution since my list is a bit large.

Comment: It's a good solution, and I think for your case you don't need the trie code, you just need an object to index (that you already done) your results and a find function to filter and ignore case or some special chars. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the trie implementation by Mike de Boer https://github.com/mikedeboer/trie to solve this. I split an item on word boundaries and stored each word in the trie. For the last letter of each word I stored the index of the item that the word came from in the trie node. When user searches, I return a list of indices and then get the corresponding items from the main list.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should try to use google or search previous question before asking such a straight forward question.

To answer your question, you could use jquery-ui wich has amoung many other widgets one called Autocomplete.
If you're familair with JQuery this should be pretty easy to implement.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I have updated the question to explain the problem a bit more. Sorry for before.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery autocomplete. ah, you've answered that already by yourself!
http://bit.ly/uXHRR0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin